# android - linearlayout in scrollview

Tags: android, user-interface, landscape, portrait

Since my UI is quite simple I'd like to cater for both landscape and portrait in one xml file.

In portrait mode everything is as I exactly want it to be.

In landscape the main_title TextView is barely shown. Is there a work around for this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:background="@color/background"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:padding="20dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dip" android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TextView android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
            android:textSize="24.5sp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/main_title" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <Button android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/start_button"
            android:text="@string/start_label" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Button>
        <TextView android:textSize="18sp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:text="@string/time_window_please_select_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:prompt="@string/time_window_prompt" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Spinner>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" android:id="@+id/status_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" android:id="@+id/status_time_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
        <ImageView android:layout_marginTop="60dip" android:id="@+id/info_button"
            android:src="@drawable/info" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="bottom|right" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Links:

http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~am907/landscape.png

http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~am907/portrait.png

Comment: could it be because of your margins and padding?  post a screenshot of what you see perhaps.  also, you might consider making your linearlayout have width/height of `wrap_content`

Comment: are you unable to see it even when scrolling?

Comment: http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~am907/portrait.png http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~am907/landscape.png

Comment: @Matthew I can't scroll up. I can only scroll down.

Comment: cant seem to access the picture you uploaded, add it to your question

Comment: my bet is the margins/padding you have setup.  remove them all and see what happens.

Comment: I removed all the margins except the padding one and it worked. So If I want to add margins, what do I do?

Comment: create 2 layout files, 1 in the `layout-land` res folder and the other in `layout` res folder.  change the one in `layout-land` to suite your liking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like the problem lies with your `margin` and `padding` values.

best option may be to have 2 different layouts for this, 1 being portrait and other being landscape.  create another folder named `layout-land` and `layout-port` in your `res` folder.  then copy the layout file into both of these folders and make appropriate changes for the orientation.

see the android docs for more info about providing different resources for different orientations and so on: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Answer (score 0):

add a blank textview at the top of the file, ie above the textview which is not visible. maybe your content area is very big and the screen is not able to support it. The problem that you are facing should not be happening in the first place.... but this is a work around. Also try switching emulators...

Comment: problem occurs on real device too. if I add two empty text views..it works in landscape...and potrait too..although in portrait main_title starts slightly further down...

Comment: i think you need to make separate folders for holding portrait and landscape view xmls.